# XSLT1.0 Import java code as utils from web (github for example)

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, xalan

Im wondering is it possible to include my java code from web into my xslt1.0 file.
Why I want to import java class from web? Because I dont have access to include util locally.

For Example (date is only example here, i wanna put some other code):

***This one below works well.***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:date="xalan://java.util.Date"
  extension-element-prefixes="date">

  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <xsl:value-of select="date:new()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***I want to achieve something like this below:***

Import this java class below from github

```
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtil {
    public static Date getDate(long time) {
    return new Date(time);
    }
}
```

into XSLT Stylesheet util

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java">

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:value-of select="java:DateUtil.getDate(1288652928119)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Compile your code and add it to the class path and reference it one of the ways shown in http://xalan.apache.org/old/xalan-j/extensions.html.

Comment: @MartinHonnen is there any solution of not adding it into classpath (I dont have acces) or include javascript code inside XSLT 1.0 ? i saw some examples of javascript from link that you gave, but none of them work for me unfortunately or maybe im doing it wrong

Comment: Are you aware that Xalan only supports XSLT 1 from 1999 while Saxon 9 or 10 support XSLT 3 from 2017 with a much better and broader support for date and dateTime data types as well as user defined functions in XSLT itself?